# Create a dynamic JSON key

Tags: karate

I need to create a test where a JSON object is generated in a .featre setting dynamically both key and value
I tried to do :

```
---
    * def myTestKey = 'key'
    * def myTestValue = 'value'
    * def myTest = { '#(myTestKey)' : '#(myTestValue)' }
    * print myTest
---
```

### The output is

```
{"#(myTestKey)": "value"}
```

---

### While the expected output is

```
{ "key":"value"}
```

---

Can you suggest me how to correctly set the key part?
Regards

Andres